# Conditional statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am trying to match data by last name and first name. Since I have multiple customers with the same name, I would like to try to see if (out of the previous query) either the phone number or street address match. Is there any way to do this in one statement?

My simple statement so far is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.LAST_NAME = table2.LAST_NAME 
AND table1.FIRST_NAME = table2.FIRST_NAME
```

I am not sure if there is a way to do something like the following in just MySQL:
IF (table1.LAST_NAME = table2.LAST_NAME) AND (table1.FIRST_NAME = table2.FIRST_NAME) equals a result AND a duplicate is found, match based on street address OR phone. And if no duplicate is found, simply match by name.

Comment: Why not always match based with additionally street address or phone?

Comment: We may have some cases where one table does not have either the address or phone number.

Comment: oh, that's not so hard, I think, let me stab at it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the extra compares optional by adding a check for blanks like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.LAST_NAME = table2.LAST_NAME 
AND table1.FIRST_NAME = table2.FIRST_NAME 
AND (table1.PHONE = table2.PHONE OR table1.PHONE = '' OR table2.PHONE = '')
AND (table1.ADDRESS = table2.ADDRESS OR table1.ADDRESS = '' OR table2.ADDRESS = '')
```

In this way, if either table's `PHONE` field is blank, the comparison will pass, and therefore have no filtering effect.

Comment: This seems to be working but if there is a name that matches, but the addresses do not, it looks like it does not return the result. For example one table lists "Maple Lane" and the other table lists "Maple LN". My big problem is that neither table has normalized data. But your answer definitely gets close to where I want to be. Thank you!

Comment: For non-normalized data, human intelligence is best, but you can get close with a set of standard adjustments done in string replacement, such as "Lane" for "LN"